# Salesforce Simple Syntax Error

Tags: apex, controller, lightning-apps, helper

I am working on a very basic lightning App that will return (for cases) a list of cases that have the same contactId associated with them. I'm following this trailhead as an example and modifying for my own purpose: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/projects/workshop-lightning-restaurant-locator/s

The browser is throwing this error:

> TypeError: Error in $A.getCallback() [fn is undefined]
>   Callback failed: aura://ComponentController/ACTION$getComponent
>   throws at ...

When I go through the logs it tells me that its expecting a semi-colon somewhere.

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement ...

The app is not completed, especially the part that returns the data to the component and displays it, so there may be other issues, but I believe it should be rendering at this stage in the page layout and I believe the error is in the apex/helper/controller.

Controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getRelatedList(component);
    }
})
```

Helper:

```
({
    getRelatedList: function(component) {
        var recordID = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.getRelated");
        action.setParams({
            "recordId": recordID
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            this.doLayout(response, component);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    // add doLayout function
    doLayout: function(response, component) {
        var data = response.getReturnValue());
        component.set("v.relatedCases", data);
        console.log("The Data: ", data);
    }  
    })
```

Apex Controller:

```
public class FreeMUNIRelatedCases{
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Case> getRelated(String recordId) {
        return [ Select CaseNumber,Status
                FROM Case WHERE ContactID = :[SELECT ContactID FROM CASE 
                                              WHERE Id = :recordId].ContactId];
    }
}
```

Lightning Component:

```
<aura:component controller="FreeMUNIRelatedCases"
                implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,
                            flexipage:availableForRecordHome, force:hasRecordId"
                            access="global">
    <!-- launch and run controller on page initialization-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    <!-- store the recordId from the record detail page in an attribute -->
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />

    <!-- The related cases returned by the Controller-->
    <aura:attribute name="relatedCases" type="Case[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="caseContact" type="String"/>

<div class="slds-box" aura:id="main">
  <div aura:id="panelList">    
    <header>
      <h2 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-m-bottom--small">
          Free MUNI Related Cases</h2>
    </header>
    <div aura:id="scrollableArea">
      <ul class="slds-list--vertical slds-has-dividers--top-space">
        <li class="slds-list__item">
            <h3 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-m-bottom--x-small">Current Case = "{!v.recordId}"</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-list__item">
            <h3 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-m-bottom--x-small">Item 2</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="slds-list__item">
            <h3 class="slds-text-heading--small slds-m-bottom--x-small">Item 3</h3>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: FYI you can make your Apex use one query instead of two by changing your inner query to a [`Left Inner Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Inner_Join), switching parentheses (`()`) for square brackets (`[]`) and removing `.ContactId`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a extra parenthesis in dolayout helper method

```
 var data = response.getReturnValue());
```

Also from your browser console if you click into the error it will show the exact line where the code is erroring out in your javascript file